# Checking a character is a vowel

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a function that will check if a letter is a vowel or not.

Why is mine always saying it is not a vowel?

```
function isItAVowel(letter) {
    var vowel = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];

    for (var i=0; i < vowel.length; i++) {
        if (letter == vowel[i]) {
            document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = "vowel";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = "not vowel";
        }
    }
}

isItAVowel("i");
```

Comment: Because you don't stop comparing after you found a match. You keep comparing the input against all letters in `vowel`. The last entry is `"u"` and `"i" == "u"` is `false`.

Comment: Also you already output false on every iteration even when there still might be a match ahead.

Comment: I think there is no need to use a for loop in order to get the same result, i will post an example

Comment: Bergi: I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: `'eaoiu'.indexOf(letter) !== -1 ? 'vowel' : 'not vowel';`

Comment: He means that you update the HTML every time you go around the for loop, rather than setting a variable that you look at after the for loop has completed and updating the HTML once.

Comment: Also, if this is pure JS (not using jQuery), you'll need to make sure that your HTML element with the id "paragraph" is defined before your JavaScript function is executed -- otherwise, the JS will bail because it can't see the DOM id before it's constructed.

Comment: Paul: I have never seen this type of code, how would I check the answer because below doesn't work? document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = 'eaoiu'.indexOf(letter) !== -1 ? 'vowel' : 'not vowel';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because once you've found a match, you need to break from the loop and exit the function.

Correct way to handle false:

```
function isItAVowel(letter) {
  var vowel = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];
  for (var i=0; i < vowel.length; i++) {
    if (letter == vowel[i]) {
      document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = "vowel";
      return;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = "not vowel";
}

isItAVowel("i");
```

Since everyone is posting fun ways of doing this differently, here is a way to do it without a function at all, with the fastest execution:

```
var isItAVowel = {
  'a': true,
  'e': true,
  'i': true,
  'o': true,
  'u': true };

!!isItAVowel["a"] == true;
!!isItAVowel["o"] == true;
!!isItAVowel["c"] == false;
```

Comment: Great.  If you test the code and it works, please remember to mark an answer as correct so other users know which solution works.

Comment: I think there is no need to use a for loop

Comment: @juangarcia The OP was asking for help with the function he wrote, not asking for a complete rewrite.

Comment: @TbWill4321 I think it is a more clear approach not to use a for loop in this case.

Comment: @juangarcia While it may be clearer, there may be a reason for OP using a native `for` loop (performance, requirements, etc)

Comment: First answer the question in the way they asked, if possible, then show different methods and what the differences are.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this is:

```
function isItAVowel(letter) {
  var vowel = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];
  document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = (vowel.indexOf(letter) >= 0) ? "vowel" : "not vowel";
}
isItAVowel('i');
```

So this way i think is more declarative to get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Break your 'for' loop once you find the letter is a vowel, otherwise your end result will be overwritten

```
document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = "vowel";
break;
```

Full code

```
function isItAVowel(letter) {
    var vowel = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];
    for (var i=0; i < vowel.length; i++) {
        if (letter == vowel[i]) {
            document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = "vowel";
            break;
        }

        else { document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = "not vowel";

        }
    }
}

isItAVowel("i");
```

An optimized version of your function without 'for' loop

```
function isItAVowel(letter) {
    var vowel = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];
    var text = vowel.indexOf(letter) != -1 ? "vowel" : "not vowel";
    document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = text;
}

isItAVowel("i");
```

Comment: Just adding a break will result in some very inefficient code

Comment: @TbWill4321 What makes it inefficient?

Comment: For non-vowels, this function will retrieve the `#paragraph` element over and over and set it's innerHTML multiple times, causing page redraws.  It should only set the element's value once, for true or false.

Comment: I don't see why you are using for loop

Comment: @TbWill4321 What you mentioned is correct, but it has nothing to do with break. DOM manipulation has to be minimal.

Comment: @juangarcia I agree with you, 'for' is not required. The original solution was taken from the question with fix for question. A more optimized solution is now added.

Comment: @kiranvj I wasn't saying the `break` was inefficient, but that *only* adding a break resulted in code that was still inefficient.

Comment: @TbWill4321, agree with that, The original solution was taken from the question with minimal code changes to fix the issue. A more optimized solution is now added.

Answer (score 1):

TbWill4321 answer is correct , but just thought of sharing this , where I avoided the for loop and used indexOf property of js array

```
function isItAVowel(letter) {
      var vowel = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];

        if (vowel.indexOf(letter) !=-1) {
          document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = "its vowel";
          return;
        }

      document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = "not vowel";
    }

    isItAVowel("x");
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y2jbnxtu/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Another short fun way using Regular expressions, but in short, yes, the guys above mentioned, you never stooped or broke the loop. Good Luck

---

**JS**

```
function isItAVowel(letter) {
    var smallLetter = letter.toLowerCase(),
        DOM = document.getElementById('paragraph');
    smallLetter.match(/[aeiou]/gi) ? DOM.innerHTML = "vowel" : DOM.innerHTML = "not vowel";
}
isItAVowel("a");
```

---

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/ToreanJoel/vq8gas4L/

---

Note that this is slower than using other options where the for loop will be way faster

Comment: I like this solution as it is more extensible than other ones by adding other criterias in a regular expression than in an array, in that case it would be something else than just a vowel but it is a good approach :)

Comment: No problem, remember there will always be more than one way to do things, experiment, have fun and enjoy - that's what makes programming so much fun!

Answer (score 1):

It is actually looping  and continuously writing into html for every element. After you found the match you can add a break like this:

```
function isItAVowel(letter) {
   var vowel = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];
   for (var i=0; i < vowel.length; i++) {     
     if (letter == vowel[i]) {
       document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = "vowel"; break;
     } else { 
       document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = "not vowel";
     }
   }
}

isItAVowel("i");
```